# JSSOR Navigation Arrows Not Working in Safari or Chrome

Tags: navigation, slider, jssor, arrows

My slider seems to work perfect in Firefox, however, when viewing the slider is Chrome or Safari, the navigation arrow do not work correctly in that they do not go to the next slide.

This slide show is full screen and responsive.

You can see the slides I'm working on at:
usfloors.isasecret.com

All the code should be there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size not specified for .jssora21ldn and .jssora21rdn

Please replace

```
.jssora21ldn {
    background: url("images/a04.png") no-repeat center; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;
}
.jssora21rdn {
    background: url("images/a04.png") no-repeat center; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;
}
```

with

```
.jssora21ldn {
    background: url("images/a04.png") no-repeat center; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;
    left: 8px; top: 123px; width: 55px; height: 55px;
}
.jssora21rdn {
    background: url("images/a04.png") no-repeat center; overflow: hidden; display: block; position: absolute; cursor: pointer;
    top: 123px; width: 55px; height: 55px; right: 8px;
}
```